# Source for BIC with residual sum of squares?

Tags: residuals, aic, bic, sums-of-squares

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_information_criterion#Gaussian_special_case) states that under certain circumstances, $\mathrm{BIC} $ can be calculated as:
$$\mathrm{BIC} = n \ln(\mathrm{RSS}/n) + k \ln(n),$$

where $\mathrm{RSS}$ is the residual sum of squares. However, I was not able to find a reliable source for it. [This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/423356/what-is-the-correct-implementation-of-bic-with-residual-sum-of-squares) question gives [another source](https://ral.ucar.edu/data/hopson/BiharTraining/Lectures/BIC.pdf), however that source is just a copy of the Wikipedia article.

[Yaffee and McGee](https://books.google.de/books?id=LSojZBiBZBgC) state that

$$\mathrm{BIC} = n \ln(\mathrm{MSE}) + k \ln(n),$$

which IMHO would be identical to the Wikipedia definition, if they did not specify

$$\mathrm{MSE} = \frac{1}{n-k}(RSS).$$

That's a definition of $\mathrm{MSE}$ that I have never seen before (due to $-k$)  and does not make a lot of sense to me.

Any references to reliable sources for BIC with residual sum of squares or an explanation of the strange definition of $\mathrm{MSE}$ is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: The $-k$ is the standard adjustment for creating an unbiased estimator of residual variance in a regression, and serves the same purpose (well is exactly the same thing) as the $-1$ in the usual calculation of variance, where you divide by $n-1$.  I'm a bit surprised you haven't run into it before :)

Comment: @jbowman Of course! Ok, I withdraw my hasty statement that I have never seen it before. Of course I have, I just did not make the connection because I'm used to only $1$ being subtracted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formulas given by [Yaffee and McGee](https://books.google.de/books?id=LSojZBiBZBgC) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_information_criterion#Gaussian_special_case) are indeed identical, except for [Bessel's correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_correction) ($-k$). Whether Bessel's correction has to be applied depends on the use case.